# Deserialize array of objects into argument resolver model

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get my model object directrly into my controller

I made an argument resolver to deserialise my incoming data to my model.

code looks like this

**Controller :**

```
    public function updateAreaModes(UpdateAreaModes $updateAreaModes, int $id)
```

**Argument resolver :**

```
public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): iterable
{
    yield $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), UpdateAreaModes::class, BaseResolver::JSON);
}
```

**Request Content :**

```
[{"type": "SomeType", "value": "someValue"}]
```

**UpdateAreaModes:**
(the model i need in my controller)

```
class UpdateAreaModes
{ 
    /** @var array<ModeDTO> */
    public array $modes;
}
```

**ModeDTO:**

```
class ModeDTO
{
    public string $type;
    public string $value;
}
```

All i get in the controller is an empty UpdateAreaModes object :(

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, not the one I was looking for but it works I guess

```
    yield $this->serializer->deserialize(
        $request->getContent(),
        ModeDTO::class . '[]',
        BaseResolver::JSON
    );
```